# Creating proper JSON using mySQL and php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am pretty sure I am mixing several tasks together, but please be patient, I am a newby in mySQL and php.

I am using `json_encode` to create JSON from mySQL query.
But before it is echoed, I would like to modify the JSON, to add more valuable data.
Currently my JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "question": "1",
    "questionText": "question text 1",
    "categoryID": "1",
    "answerID": "1",
    "answerText": "answer text 1",
    "isTrue": "1"
  },
  {
    "question": "1",
    "questionText": "question text 1",
    "categoryID": "1",
    "answerID": "2",
    "answerText": "answer text 2",
    "isTrue": "0"
  },
  {
    "question": "1",
    "questionText": "question text 1",
    "categoryID": "1",
    "answerID": "3",
    "answerText": "answer text 3",
    "isTrue": "0"
  },
  {
    "question": "1",
    "questionText": "question text 1",
    "categoryID": "1",
    "answerID": "4",
    "answerText": "answer text 4",
    "isTrue": "0"
  },
  {
    "question": "2",
    "questionText": "question text 2",
    "categoryID": "2",
    "answerID": "1",
    "answerText": "answer text 1",
    "isTrue": "0"
  },
  {
    "question": "2",
    "questionText": "question text 2",
    "categoryID": "2",
    "answerID": "2",
    "answerText": "answer text 2",
    "isTrue": "1"
  },
  {
    "question": "2",
    "questionText": "question text 2",
    "categoryID": "2",
    "answerID": "3",
    "answerText": "answer text 3",
    "isTrue": "0"
  },
  {
    "question": "2",
    "questionText": "question text 2",
    "categoryID": "2",
    "answerID": "4",
    "answerText": "answer text 4",
    "isTrue": "0"
  }
]
```

I would like it to look like this (pseudo code):

```
    exam:{
    questions:[
        question:{
            questionID: string
            questionTest: string
            categoryID: string
            correctAnswerID: string
            chosenAnswerID: string
            answers:[
                answer:{
                    answerID = string
                    answerText = string
                    isTrue = bool
                }
                answer:{}
            ]
        }
        question:{}
     ]
     categoryID: string
 }
```

and here is the code so far:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","Theory");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `questions`.`questionID` AS questionID,
                           `questions`.`questionText` AS questionText,
                           `questions`.`categoryID` AS categoryID,
                           `answers`.`answerID` AS answerID,
                           `answers`.`answerText` AS answerText,
                           `answers`.`isTrue` AS isTrue
                                 FROM `questions`,`answers`
                                 WHERE `questions`.`questionID` = `answers`.`questionID`");

    if (!$result)
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

   $rows = array();
   while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
   }
   print json_encode($rows);

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

</body>
</head>
```

Comment: I would build a new object beforehand and then `json_encode` that final object.

Comment: @WillemEllis Is this a good place to start for this? http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/object-oriented-php-for-beginners/

Comment: You won't be able to use `question` or `answer` as a key in a list/object more than once. They will need to be unique and it will be a list if you use numerical keys.

Comment: @DigitalFiz that's fine but where do I start figuring this out?

Comment: That link you sent is a good start. I am working on a good answer for you with comments to explain what I did. Stand bye :D

Comment: @WillemEllis I have broken the question to parts. I guess, first I need to understand how to propagate variables of an instance of an object from mySQL data using php. I'll appreciate your help over there 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684510/creating-instance-from-mysql-data-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal preference and for ease of use I would avoid joining the question and answers tables together. Especially since you need to separate them in the json anyways. Here is a rewrite with some comments to help you understand what is going on. **NOTICE: Code has not be tested with a database so it may not work exactly as I don't know the structure of your tables but it should get you started.**

```
<?php 

// header information needs to be set before any output or it will error.
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

?><html>
    <body>

<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","Theory");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$questions = array();

// Lets get a list of the questions
$questions_results = mysql_query("SELECT `questions`.`questionID`, `questions`.`questionText`, `questions`.`categoryID` FROM `questions`") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
while($question = mysqli_fetch_object($questions_results))
{

    // Now that we have a $question object lets add an answers property and set it to a blank array
    $questions[$question->questionID]->answers = array();

    // Now query for answers table to build on the answers array
    $answers_results = mysql_query("SELECT `answers`.`answerID`, `answers`.`answerText`, `answers`.`isTrue` FROM `answers` where `answers`.`questionID` = '".$question->questionID."'") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    while($answer = mysqli_fetch_object($questions_results))
    {
        $questions[$question->questionID]->answers[] = $answer;
    }

    // Now lets add this nifty new question to the $questions array
    $questions[] = $question;
}
mysqli_close($con);


// Now we can prin the json version of $questions
json_encode($questions);

?>

    </body>
</head>
```

What the above code does is it builds an array/object that if built by hand would be built like this:

```
        // Question 1 - Notice the 0 key index on the q
        $questions[0] = new stdClass(); // Create a new object
        $questions[0]->questionID = 1;
        $questions[0]->questionText = "Question";
        $questions[0]->categoryID = 1;
        $questions[0]->answers = array(); // Create a new array for answers

            // Answer 1 for question 1 - notice the 0 key index on the answer
            $questions[0]->answers[0] = new stdClass(); // Create a new object for answer 1
            $questions[0]->answers[0]->answerID = 1;
            $questions[0]->answers[0]->answerText = "Answer";
            $questions[0]->answers[0]->isTrue = 1;

            // Answer 2 for question 1 - notice the 1 key index on the answer
            $questions[0]->answers[1] = new stdClass(); // Create a new object for answer 1
            $questions[0]->answers[1]->answerID = 1;
            $questions[0]->answers[1]->answerText = "Answer";
            $questions[0]->answers[1]->isTrue = 1;


        // Question 2 - notice the 1 key index on the questions
        $questions[1] = new stdClass(); // Create a new object
        $questions[1]->questionID = 1;
        $questions[1]->questionText = "Question";
        $questions[1]->categoryID = 1;
        $questions[1]->answers = array(); // Create a new array for answers

            // Answer 1 for question 2
            $questions[1]->answers[0] = new stdClass(); // Create a new object for answer 1
            $questions[1]->answers[0]->answerID = 1;
            $questions[1]->answers[0]->answerText = "Answer";
            $questions[1]->answers[0]->isTrue = 1;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alter your object before actually encoding it.

If you receive JSON from a third party source (just in case, this is not related to the current situation), you need to parse it, modify it and then encode it again.

By far more efficient than trying string parsing on a JSON...

Comment: Ok, I have breaken the question to parts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684510/creating-instance-from-mysql-data-using-php. I guess, first I need to understand how to propagate variables of an instance of an object from mySQL data using php